# Javascript and Jsp page

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

This might be very simple one but i am not understanding where i am doing wrong. I have a form which has three links, namely LogIn,SignUp and ForgotPassword. I used javascript document..action to set action for these links using a simple switch case. while Singup and ForgotPassword refer to singup.jsp and ForgotPassword.jsp respectively, LogIn link refers to a servlet. And i used url-pattern given in web.xml file as its target. when i run it gives error upon clicking on sigin. Any idea what's going wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function redirect(tid)
    {
      switch(tid)
      {
        case "a":
        {
            if(document.form.Username.value=='')
            {
                alert("Enter your username");
                return false;
            }
            if(document.form.Password.value=='')
            {
                alert("Enter your password");
                return false;
            }
             document.form.action="check" //check is the urlpattern defined for checkUser servlet
        }
        break;
        case "b":
            document.form.action="Signup.jsp"
            break;

        case "c":
            document.form.action="Forgotpassword.jsp"
            break;
     }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show us some relevant source code? Otherwise it's hard to tell what exactly went wrong.

Comment: Please refer to the code posted

Comment: The error is HTTP POST method is not supported by this URL

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
document.forms[0].action = 'Forgotpassword.jsp';
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment on the question:

> *The error is HTTP POST method is not supported by this URL*

The servlet which is listening on the URL does not have the `doPost()` method overridden. Apparently you're using a `<form method="post">` to submit to a servlet which has only `doGet()` implemented. You need to rename the `doGet()` method to `doPost()`.

Please note that this has **nothing** to do with the JavaScript code which you posted in the question.